# OpenMPI 1.6.3- 64 bit installation failure in CentOS 6.3

Tags: linux, cuda, installation, centos, openmpi

How to install **OpenMPI 1.6.3 - 64 bit** version in a machine with **CUDA 5.0** installed already. OS using is **CentOS 6.3 x86_64**.

After doing the **configure** i gave the command **make**. At last it is showing some conflict with the CUDA include files.

I
 have gave the following options in configure command

```
./configure --enable-heterogeneous --enable-cxx-exceptions --enable-opal-multi-threads --enable-mpi-thread-multiple --with-wrapper-cflags=-m64 --with-wrapper-cxxflags=-m64 --with-wrapper-ldflags=-m64 --with-wrapper-libs=-m64 --with-wrapper-fflags=-m64 --with-wrapper-fcflags=-m64 --with-exflags=-m64 --with-timer=TYPE CFLAGS=-m64 LDFLAGS=-m64 CPPFLAGS=-m64 CXXFLAGS=-m64 CCASFLAGS=-m64 FFLAGS=-m64 FCFLAGS=-m64 --prefix=/usr/local/openmpi
```

configure command successfully executed. After that i gave

```
make
```

After a lot of output i got the following errors in the terminal.

```
Making all in vtlib
make[5]: Entering directory `/Softwares/OpenMPI/openmpi-1.6.3/ompi/contrib/vt/vt/vtlib'
  CC     vt_comp_gnu.lo
  CC     vt_getcpu.lo
  CC     vt_gpu.lo
  CC     vt_cudartwrap.lo
vt_cudartwrap.c:145: error: conflicting types for 'cudaGetSymbolAddress'
/usr/local/cuda/include/cuda_runtime_api.h:4263: note: previous declaration of 'cudaGetSymbolAddress' was here
vt_cudartwrap.c:164: error: conflicting types for 'cudaGetSymbolSize'
/usr/local/cuda/include/cuda_runtime_api.h:4285: note: previous declaration of 'cudaGetSymbolSize' was here
vt_cudartwrap.c:392: error: conflicting types for 'cudaGetTextureReference'
/usr/local/cuda/include/cuda_runtime_api.h:5055: note: previous declaration of 'cudaGetTextureReference' was here
vt_cudartwrap.c:501: error: conflicting types for 'cudaFuncGetAttributes'
/usr/local/cuda/include/cuda_runtime_api.h:2241: note: previous declaration of 'cudaFuncGetAttributes' was here
vt_cudartwrap.c:797: error: conflicting types for 'cudaFuncSetCacheConfig'
/usr/local/cuda/include/cuda_runtime_api.h:2122: note: previous declaration of 'cudaFuncSetCacheConfig' was here
vt_cudartwrap.c:969: error: conflicting types for 'cudaGetSurfaceReference'
/usr/local/cuda/include/cuda_runtime_api.h:5110: note: previous declaration of 'cudaGetSurfaceReference' was here
vt_cudartwrap.c:1565: error: conflicting types for 'cudaFuncSetSharedMemConfig'
/usr/local/cuda/include/cuda_runtime_api.h:2173: note: previous declaration of 'cudaFuncSetSharedMemConfig' was here
make[5]: *** [vt_cudartwrap.lo] Error 1
make[5]: Leaving directory `/Softwares/OpenMPI/openmpi-1.6.3/ompi/contrib/vt/vt/vtlib'
make[4]: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
make[4]: Leaving directory `/Softwares/OpenMPI/openmpi-1.6.3/ompi/contrib/vt/vt'
make[3]: *** [all] Error 2
make[3]: Leaving directory `/Softwares/OpenMPI/openmpi-1.6.3/ompi/contrib/vt/vt'
make[2]: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
make[2]: Leaving directory `/Softwares/OpenMPI/openmpi-1.6.3/ompi/contrib/vt'
make[1]: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory `/Softwares/OpenMPI/openmpi-1.6.3/ompi'
make: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
```

Comment: OpenMPI yet doesn't support CUDA 5. So either install an older version of the toolkit, or compile with `--disable-cudawrap`. But this question is off topic for Stackoverflow. Take it to the OpenMPI users mailing list or similar.

Comment: The problem is not in Open MPI buth rather with the bundled VampirTrace library. Simply configure the build with `--disable-vt`. 1.6.1 does not build VT by default. Maybe 1.6.3 had this changed. If you need MPI tracing, obtain the latest VampirTrace from its home site and build it separately.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is not in Open MPI buth rather with the bundled VampirTrace library. **Simply configure the build with *--disable-vt***. 1.6.1 does not build VT by default. Maybe 1.6.3 had this changed. If you need MPI tracing, obtain the latest VampirTrace from its home site and build it separately.

This answer is provided by **Hristo Iliev Nov 16 at 12:35**